# Position operator action on a wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, dirac-delta-distributions, measurement-problem

In a 1 dimensional infinite potential well with width $a$, the ground state wave-function is given by
$$\psi(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin(\frac{\pi}{a}x)$$

The action of the position operator in the position space is defined as
$$\hat{X}\psi(x) = x\psi(x)$$

Basically, in the case above, I would write
$$\phi(x) = x\psi(x) = x\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin(\frac{\pi}{a}x)$$

**What does this new function mean?**

For example, if I would write a code to simulate the action of $\hat{X}$, should I just multiply $x$ with $\psi(x)$, (and which $x$ ?) or should I use *if* and *else* statements and at some satisfied condition I plot the delta function at some position $x_0$, i. e. $\delta(x-x_0)$ ?

---

**Update and an answer (if there are any corrections to make, don't hesitate!)**

After some thinking and reopening old forgotten paper from school years, I can say the following (It could be right or wrong):

The equation: $\hat{X}\psi(x) = x\psi(x)$ is a definition (a construction) that says, when ever I find $\hat{X}$ acting on some \psi(x), I replace it with $x\psi(x)$. This is the case, for example, when calculating the expectation value: $\langle x\rangle = \int \psi^*(x) ~\hat{X}~\psi(x)dx = \int \psi^*(x) ~x~\psi(x)dx$. This makes the integral in the familiar mathematical shape, so we can deal with it.

However, $\psi(x)$ is an *energy* eigenstate (in the example above). We can write it in the position basis, by knowing that the eigenfunctions of $\hat{X}$ are the Dirac-delta function, so

$$\psi(x) = \int \psi(x)\delta(x-x_0)dx$$
Now this will yield

$$\hat{X}\psi(x) = x\psi(x) = \int x\psi(x)\delta(x - x_0)dx = x_0\psi(x_0)$$

Once I write the energy eigenfunction $\psi(x)$ in the position basis, I get the *position eigenvalues* from it.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You correctly stated the action of $X$ on the wave function. Where exactly is the problem now? Can you elaborate? If you know how to implement the function $\sin(x)$, where is the problem in implementing $x\sin(x)$?

Comment: Yes, I can implement $x~sin(x)$, but what does this new function mean? What about the last line in my question?

Comment: What do you mean with "what does it mean" at all?! It has a priori no meaning--why do you think it has some meaning?. Yes I don't understand the last question. As you said, the action of $X$ is $(X\psi)(x)=x\psi(x)$.

Comment: For this specific case mentioned in the question, let's say the width $a$ is 1, so $x$ has values [0,..., 0.1, ..., 0.5,..., 0.7, ...., 1] . Is $x$, which I multiply with $\psi$, an array of these values, or is it one of them?

Comment: I think $x$ would be some subarray of [0, 1].

Comment: (I THINK) the position operator is $\hat{X}= \int \mathrm{d}{x}'|{x}'\rangle\langle {x}' |$. So it is continuous. You have to discretized it to put it into a code.

Comment: That's not my question. Even in plotting $\psi$ itself, the x values are discrete. The question is not about how to code, it is about *what* to code.

Comment: I think you have not understood the definition of $X$. Take your interval of possible $x$ and the function you mention $\sin(x)$. Now on each possible value for $x$, you get a value for $\sin(x)$. Where is now the problem to compute the value $x\sin(x)$ for each value of $x$?!

Comment: I cannot tell you more than what you wrote already: $(X\psi)(x):=x\psi(x)$.

Comment: Sorry, the answer came late. But great. So when I plot $x~ \sin(x)$, for the ground state, and $x = [0,1]$, I get a hill shifted to the bigger values of $x$, so to the right of the box. I don't get much of that. But if $x$ is *some* subarray of [0,1], I should get non-zero values only inside this subarray

Answer (score 2):

When using operators, one can calculate statistic values, like for example average position
$< \psi| \hat{X}|\psi> = \int \psi^* \hat{X} \psi \, \mathrm{d}x $
otherwise your function $\phi$ itself does not mean much for me.

Comment: If it doesn't mean much, then why I find this definition of the action of $\hat{X}$ in every single textbook? What I think is, this $x$ is a subarray of the entire $x$ values in the system. In the case of 1D well, $x$ is some subarray of $[0, a]$.

Comment: The function $X\psi$, i.e. the function obtained by acting with the position operator on a given function, does indeed mean nothing a priori. As I asked before: Why do you expect it has a meaning? And you should specify what you mean with "mean". Think about where QM actually makes predictions for experiments, as the answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The components $X_k$ of the position operator $\vec X$ generate the moments of the spatial distribution of mass and charge in a pure state represented by an wave function $\psi$.

$$ \mathbb E_\psi \left (X_k^n \right) = \int \psi(x)^* \ \  x_k^n \ \ \psi(x) \ d^3x $$

The importance of the position operator is twice,

1. it is the operator in the argument of the the electromagnetic potentials $\Phi(\vec X), \vec A(\vec X)$, that shift energy and momentum origins from point to point as in classical mechanics.
2. in the interaction with an em plane wave $\Phi = e^{i k x}$, the extension of a bound state in atom and molecules of $ 10^{-10}m $ for wavelengths larger than $10^{-7} m$ is slow and acts only in a tiny volume. The factor of atomic dimensions, the Bohr radius, and the em wavelenghts involved in interaction  is given by the fine structure constant $\alpha=1/136\dots$, that represents the interaction constant in the QED theory of radiation.

From these numbers, for all purposes, the electromagnetic wave, interacting with  bound states in atoms, can be replaced by its spatial linear approximation
$$\Phi(t,x) = e^{i \omega t- k x)}=e^{i \omega t}\ (1 -i k x)$$

The reaction of the electron in a bound state to an external em wave is similar to a samll mechanical pendulum clock, moving  up and down by some $1000 m$, very slowly wrt. to its own frequency, changing its period by the change of the gradient of the potential.

The rate of change for a jump between two bound states is given by the the square of the dipole moment between the two wave functions.

$$\mathbb E\left( (1/T)_{\psi\to\phi}\right) = \text{const} \ \left| \int \psi(x)^* \ x_k \ \phi(x) \ d^3x \ \right|^2 $$

This formula, the Born approximation, that explains most of atomic spectra and its statistics, historically was the reason, why the total inconceivable Schrödinger theory made its immediate breakthrough.

In your special case, in the dipole approximation the two lowest states in the intervall $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ are
$$\cos x, \sin 2x$$
[image: bound states in a box]

The expectation of X yields
$$\frac{\left(\int_{-\pi /2}^{\pi/2} x \sin (2 x) \cos (x) \, dx\right)^2}{137 \left(\int_{-\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \sin ^2(2 x) \, dx\right) \left(\int_{-\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \cos ^2(x) \, dx\right)}=\frac{256}{11097 \pi ^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for writing that, but actually my question is much simpler than this. I am just asking, that in case I've written a code about the action of $\hat{X}$ on , say, the ground state of a particle in a well, what values of x would be multiplied by $\psi$ ? The entire [0, a] values array, or some subarray of it ?

Comment: A linear operator maps a function to another function. The better way to deal with this problem would be to find a convergent polynomial approximation of your wave function and to multiply that polynomial with x, which gives you a new polynomial that's one order higher. The blunt-force discretization of partial differential equations is numerically almost always disastrous.